# How to search particular URL in all over web through php

Tags: php, seo

I want to search a particular url from all over the web.
like if i search for `www.stackoverflow.com` then it displays those URL who uses the `www.stackoverflow.com` links in their site or webpages. i want to do that through PHP script. Please help me how to that or provide some URLs from where i can find the help for solution.

Comment: Make use of `strpos()` in PHP.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: I want to find through all over the web not from a string.

Comment: So you want to parse the complete internet for links to stackoverflow?

Comment: I want to search from the complete internet to find where the particular link is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems almost impossible to do this by crawling the web yourself. Even Google has issues with that. It is possible though by using a tool like MajesticSEO API. Not sure if it's free. I believe they only have the API for paid customers.

MajesticSEO API provides you with link information to root-, subdomain or page level link data. And it will help you to come close to what I think you are looking for. You can pull the data with PHP and use it in any way you want. If it's allowed by their conditions of course.

http://developer-support.majesticseo.com/api/